# Running Fedora 8, never upgraded. How to do so?

Tags: fedora

I'm a student working on a website for my robotics team. I've recently decided to experiment with a node.js/CouchDB setup instead of our current LAMP configuration. While trying to install these systems, I was appalled to discover that our current version of Fedora (version 8) is almost two years past EOL.
If I were to upgrade our server, what version of Fedora should I install, and how should I do this?

Thanks,
-Trey

Comment: My suggestion to you go with fresh install of FC14 :)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bad idea, but all I can think of. Try using the preupgrade tool to work your way all the way up to the latest version (Fedora 14 Laughlin). Follow this [guideline](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/YumUpgradeFaq). It should work and hopefully not break anything.